# Node.js. Как вывести строки через Rows?

Tags: node.js, cookie, сессия, requests

Пытаюсь произвести вывод строк с помощью команды в Node.js и express-session ( req.session.user2.rows[0].name ) Однако данная команда позволяет вывести только одну строку. Кто может подсказать команду которая может выводить столько строк сколько было в нее записано ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rows это ведь массив, вы берете первый его элемент с помощью rows[0]
Вам необходимо пройтись циклом по нему, чтобы вывести все данные.
что то типа этого из ES6

```
for (let row of  req.session.user2.rows){console.log(row.name)}
```

или методов массива

```
req.session.user2.rows.forEach(row => console.log(row.name)) 
req.session.user2.rows.map(row => console.log(row.name))
```

или классика

```
for(var i =0, len = req.session.user2.rows.length; i

{console.log(req.session.user2.rows[i].name)}
```

Comment: Если у меня такое действие с выборкой с запроса БД.
`client.query (select name,last_name from pupil) where name = '$1' and last_name = '$2',[req.session.user2.rows[0].name,req.session.user2.rows[0].last_name]` При таком вводе оно работает, а когда стараюсь использователть один из методов выше, он не происходит (хотя в console.log выводит)

Comment: Что то не так с реализацией, судя по всему запросы в цикле (а это очень плохая практика). Используйте фильтрацию до и/или после запросов в базу.

Comment: Что именно вы имеете введу под "фильтрацией"

Comment: Дал ответ в другом Вашем вопросе.
Смысл в том, что если запрос выполняете в цикле - то нужно будет где то хранить результаты. Как вариант создать переменную userArr и пушить туда результаты выгрузки.
Скажется на производительности приложения, т.к. каждая итерация требует время для выполнения.
Рекомендую использовать IN (select * from table where user2 in ()) и подставлять все значения, которые хотите получить